# How to bypass routing in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I'm creating a web application in which the bulk of the functionality is deployed as an AngularJS single-page application, but there are also a few static content pages that are served in the traditional way.

Navigation within the SPA employs Angular UI Router and seems to be working correctly, as does the serving of the static pages.

However, the code architecture is such that all scripts are referenced from within the main site template and are thus served with every page, including the static pages. This is a deliberate decision, as there are some scripted features that need to accessible from everywhere, even from within the static pages.

For example, the header region of every page contains a search box with typeahead, that allows users to navigate to a view within the SPA, populated to reflect the selected content.

If a search is invoked from within the SPA, everything works as expected, and the routing mechanism correctly executes the required state transition to render the selected content. However, if the same search is conducted from within one of the static pages, although UI Router correctly processes the state transition, the content is not rendered because the static page does not contain the `<ui-view>` element that is usually targeted by rendering.

Although I can see what's causing the problem, I'm not sure how best to resolve it. From a novice perspective, it seems that I need to intercept the content search/selection process and execute different logic, depending on whether or not the search was invoked from within the SPA or a static page. I anticipate something like this:

```
if ($state.current.name) {
    // The search was invoked from within the SPA, so only a state change is required.
    $state.go("render", { key: selected_key });
} else {
    // The search was invoked from a static page, so an SPA page load is required

    What can we do here to bypass routing and issue a
    server request for the corresponding SPA deep-linked page?

}
```

But I'm willing to guess that there is a more elegant way of dealing with this issue, maybe one that's baked into Angular UI Router.

Any suggestions please?

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing a similar problem, the solution is actually very simple.

Instead of attempting to intercept and coerce the state transition, the desired behavior can be achieved through a simple modification to the main page template, enabling all pages, including static pages, to participate in Angular view rendering.

In my original implementation only the SPA page used the `<ui-view>` element, which resulted in the static pages ignoring the rendering that typically occurs during a state transition.

To solve the problem, I eliminated the `<ui-view>` element from the SPA page and, instead, added a `ui-view` attribute to the containing element in the main page template:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        ... page head content goes here ...
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <div ui-view>
            ... server-generated page content is injected here ...
        </div>
        ... page scripts are referenced here ...
    </body>
</html>
```

With this change in place, every page is now effectively an SPA and capable of re-rendering to reflect state transitions (albeit that most of the time this never occurs, since the user simply views the pre-rendered content that was delivered by the server).